Which Greek word was used in the text "Charmides" which was translated as "science" in some translations, or as "knowledge" in others?
I wanted to know which Greek word was used in the text Charmides which was translated as "science" in some translations and as "knowledge" in others.
For example,

“Isn’t medicine knowledge of health?” I asked. Charmides

and in this other,

Is not medicine, I said, the science of health? Charmides

PS: not sure if this fits better here or in Philosophy SE or in History of Science and Mathematics SE

I know you wouldn't know it from the name, but in the future, the Latin site will answer all questions about ancient Greek.

The Platonic Foundation has page numberings in the text, and it is thus possible to identify the passage you ask about is on 165C, which helps identifying it in the original, even without deeper knowledge of Ancient Greek.
The original text can be found on Wikisource for example:

καὶ γάρ, ἦν δ' ἐγώ, σκοπῶ. εἰ γὰρ δὴ γιγνώσκειν γέ τί ἐστιν ἡ σωφροσύνη, δῆλον ὅτι ἐπιστήμη τις ἂν εἴη καὶ τινός: ἢ οὔ;
ἔστιν, ἔφη, ἑαυτοῦ γε.
οὐκοῦν καὶ ἰατρική, ἔφην, ἐπιστήμη ἐστὶν τοῦ ὑγιεινοῦ;

(Transliteration with the help of Google Translate, so maybe some of it is not correct for ancient greek. Thanks for the improvements by Carlos Martin!)

kaí gár, en d'egó, skopó. Ei gár dè gignóskein gé tí estin e sofrosýne, délon óti epistéme tis án eíe kaí tinós: e oú?
éstin, éfe, heautoú ge.
oukoún kaí iatriké, éfen, epistéme estín toú ygieinoú?

The word used is Episteme. See the remarks:

Plato, following Xenophanes, contrasts episteme with doxa: common belief or opinion. The term episteme is also distinguished from techne: a craft or applied practice. In the Protagoras, Plato's Socrates notes that nous and episteme are prerequisites for prudence (phronesis).

But then, as is often the case with the Dialogs, there has been a whole bunch of academic interpretations of that passage.
